# How to generate transcript from URL of PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

I am working on a project where i have to display PDF file in `iframe`, i also need to display the transcript (content) of PDF file when user upload it (similar to slideshare).

Suggest me some tools/library/tutorials which works with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Simples way is google docs. It will work for your office files as well such as .doc, docx, xls, ppt etc.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php echo rawurlencode("http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql_tutorial.pdf"); ?>&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```